# How do I select an image to animate?

Tags: jquery, html

I am having trouble animating an image.  Could you please help?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#cats').click(function(){
$(this).animate(
{left:"+=500px'},
1000);
});
</script>
<title>Birman Cats</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>  Black Cat Superstitions</h1>
<div id="black">
<h2>  Folk Lore</h2>
<div id="cats">
<p><img src="images1/trees.jpg"/></p></div>
```

Comment: you have " and ' which is problem. should be {left:"+=500px"},

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed your ready function and quotings are different and you said to select image to animate but you are targeting the div, So, are you trying to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#cats').click(function(){
      $(this).find('img').animate(
        {left:"+=500px"},
      1000);
   });
});
```

Comment: How do I select the image I want to animate and how do I use the id "cats".  Sorry to be so dense but I have searched everywhere and most assume I know somethings already.  I am newbie to this.

Comment: @user3537774 , it is already written in the code .please see code .we do magic in code ,it doesnt happen automatically

Answer (score 0):

CSS `left` only works with [positioned elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left).

So your code will only work, if you assign some position 
to the inside element.

change your css code to :

```
#cats img{
    position:absolute;
    height: 100px;
}
```

and then the javascript code to apply the `left` style directly to the image

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#cats').click(function () {
        $("#cats img").animate({
            left: "+=500"
        },
        1000);
    });
});
```

updated [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/57997/)

Answer (score 0):

Working fiddle => http://jsfiddle.net/Lr8GB/  ,Use margin-left

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#cats').click(function(){
      $(this).find('img').animate(
        {'margin-left':"+=500px"},
      1000);
   });
});
</script>
```